# Need Jolt Spec to convert matrix json to denormalized json formart

Tags: json, jolt, denormalization, jsonconverter

Can anyone please help me a **JOLT spec** to convert my matrix type json to denormalized json. Please find the below my input json and my expected josn output.

**Input Json:**

```
[
  {
    "attributes": [
      {
        "name": "brand",
        "value": "Patriot Lighting"
      },
      {
        "name": "color",
        "value": "Chrome"
      },
      {
        "name": "price",
        "value": "49.97 USD"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "attributes": [
      {
        "name": "brand",
        "value": "Masterforce"
      },
      {
        "name": "color",
        "value": "Green"
      },
      {
        "name": "price",
        "value": "99.0 USD"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Expected Json output:**

```
  [
    {
      "brand": "Patriot Lighting",
      "color": "Chrome",
      "price": "49.97 USD"
    },
    {
      "brand": "Masterforce",
      "color": "Green",
      "price": "99.0 USD"
    }
  ]
```

I was trying to build JOLT spec to convert this json. But challenge is the json which I have multiple tables with "attributes" tag.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOLT is not easy to use but I get a lot out of some other StackOverflow questions floating around and I just started reading up on [the source code comments](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/blob/master/jolt-core/src/main/java/com/bazaarvoice/jolt/Shiftr.java)

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      // for each element in the array
      "*": {
        "attributes": {
          // for each element in the attribute
          "*": {
            // grab the value
            // - put it in an array
            //   - but it must be indexed by the "positions" found four steps back
            // - put the value in a key
            //   - that is determined by moving one step back and looking at member name
            "value": "[#4].@(1,name)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

This is seems very obscure at first glance but I hope the comments explain everything.

Please go read on [JOLT transformation to copy single value along an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50413213/jolt-transformation-to-copy-single-value-along-an-array#50438480)

Also this is almost mandatory for JOLT beginners https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1sAiuiFC4Lzz4-064sg1p8EQt2ev0o442MfEbvrpD1ls/edit#slide=id.g9a487080_011

If you need another example, I just answered a question here [Nifi JOLT: flat JSON object to a list of JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66580735/nifi-jolt-flat-json-object-to-a-list-of-json-object)

And, probably your best friend can be found at https://jolt-demo.appspot.com