# Nifi JOLT: flat JSON object to a list of JSON object

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am trying with Nifi JOLT processor to shift the flat JSON object to a list of JSON object as in below output. The params  `"p_7_1_0"`, `"px_2_7_1_0"`, `"pv_7_1_1"` may be different in names or numbers (e.g. I could have **{ "timestamp": 1559347670, "pw_2_1_0": 1, "p_2_2_1_0": 1 }** )

Could someone help me with the jolt specs?

**Input Json**:

```json
{
  "timestamp": 1559347670,
  "p_7_1_0": 6,
  "px_2_7_1_0": 1,
  "pv_7_1_1": 1
}
```

**Expected output JSON**:

```json
{
  "values": [
    {
      "key": "p_7_1_0",
      "value": 6,
      "timestamp": 1559347670
    },
    {
      "key": "px_2_7_1_0",
      "value": 1,
      "timestamp": 1559347670
    },
    {
      "key": "pv_7_1_1",
      "value": 1,
      "timestamp": 1559347670
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading up on this question [JOLT transformation to copy single value along an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50413213/jolt-transformation-to-copy-single-value-along-an-array#50438480)

and the answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50438480/2733184

I can see that what you want is eerily similar. However, I would have never hit the nail on the head with the question that needed to be asked.

I encourage you to go to the aforementioned Q and the A, read all of it (including the comments inside the spec) and give them some upvotes.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "timestamp": "timestamp",
      // put everything but the timestamp in a member (the pivot)
      "*": "all.&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "all": {
        "*": {
          // grab the member key and put it in its final place
          "$": "values[#2].key",
          // grab the member value and put it in its final place
          "@": "values[#2].value",
          // Walk back two steps (* -> all -> root) and grab the timestamp
          "@(2,timestamp)": "values[#2].timestamp"
          // I wish I understood the logic behind "#2" but I don't
          // and I'll have to read on it further
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I hope someone can explain what `#` is for. My immediate guess is that it is like `&` (the member name) but it looks like it is the member position (?).

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You just can loop through the attributes having **`_`** character to distinguish from **`timestamp`** within a single **shift** transformation spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*_*": {
        "@1,timestamp": "values[#2].timestamp",
        "$": "values[#2].key",
        "@": "values[#2].value"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where

- **`"@1,timestamp"`** represents grabbing the value of timestamp attribute after going one level up the tree
- by **`[#2]`** on the right-hand-side would logically mean traversing **`:`** and **`{`** as summed up **2** levels to reach the level of the topmost attributes while **`[# ]`** will generate arraywise results